# How do I access an array elements from my class in a for loop

Tags: python, class

What is wrong with this code? I am new to python and coding object oriented and I do not know how to access these values...

Code:

```
class Stock():

    def __init__(self, foodArray, quantityArray):
        self._foodArray = foodArray
        self._quantity = quantityArray

    def printStock(self):
        for i in range(len(self._foodArray)):
            print(self._foodArray[i] + ' ' + self._quantity[i])
```

expected:
a 1
b 2
c 4
x 100
etc...

Comment: What's the input? What output are you expecting? Will the two lists always be the same length? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @SimonFlodin, is `foodArray` a list of  strings and `quantityArray` a list of numbers?

Comment: yes foodArray is an array of string and quantity is numbers! Your solution was great :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that you are trying to "concatenate" an element of a list of strings (foods) with an element of a list of numbers (quantities). Assuming both arrays have the same length, and that you are using Python 3.6+, use the following:

```
class Stock():    
    def __init__(self, foodArray, quantityArray):
        self._foodArray = foodArray
        self._quantity = quantityArray

    def printStock(self):
        for i in range(len(self._foodArray)):
            print(f'{self._foodArray[i]} {self._quantity[i]}')
```

In case you are using a version of Python prior to 3.6, change the print statement to:

```
print('{} {}'.format(self._foodArray[i], self._quantity[i]))
```

You can even simplify that method using the following:

```
def printStock(self):
    for food, quantity in zip(self._foodArray, self._quantity):
        print(f'{food} {quantity}')
```

#### Working Example:

```
>>> s = Stock(['apple', 'banana', 'coconut'], [1, 2, 3])
>>> s.printStock()
apple 1
banana 2
coconut 3
```